# cart vs. mini cart issue ... rwd theme

Tags: cart, mini-cart

I use the rwd theme (slightly modified but not this part) and my cart (before checkout) shows a strange behaviour.
The part with the "item-options" is only shown on some items.
I mean the part

```
  <?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                <dd<?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?> class="truncated"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                <div class="truncated_full_value">
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                        <dd><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?></dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif;?>
```

which will be included in the **/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml**.

Until now I can't find a reason for this. The mini cart in the header contains this part and for every item.

I could narrow down the problem a little with what I tried so far:
Using **/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml** from the base theme changes nothing, but if I remove the part for the header mini cart in **/layout/checkout.xml** everything is fine.

But I cant't see why the (unchanged) header mini cart could cause this issue.
And to make it more weird, this demo shop (which uses the rwd theme) doesn't have the issue: [see here](http://clients-sherodesigns.com/newstore/).

Any thoughts what I could do or check?
Thanks.

Comment: can you some screen shot what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe give an example of which products to add to cart to view the problem.  That would help so the problem could be understood more clearly.

Comment: Sure. Ok, I have made 3 screenshots. I added 2 items to the cart, opened the cart page in another tab, made a screenshot. Then I added 2 more items, opened the cart page in another tab ... and so on. https://www.dropbox.com/s/79j8ip8ga0ydj76/2-items-in-cart.png?dl=0 ... https://www.dropbox.com/s/cy7dxqlr4vflq1e/4-items-in-cart.png?dl=0 ... https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5pjsyzfgsxim7r/6-items-in-cart.png?dl=0

Comment: As you can see, on some items there is is nothing below the SKU number. If I add more items the same items suddenly have the additional informations, but not the new items.

Comment: To make it more clear https://www.dropbox.com/s/mn66vl4wbrcl6yy/cart.png?dl=0

Comment: We've got the same problem here - out Magento crack doesn't have a clue, so far.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it was driving me crazy, as it turns out this was caused by jquery-1.10.2.min.js (or jquery in general) being loaded twice, the second time by a module. I stopped the module from loading jquery and the minicart now functions as the demo site you linked.